# Is "say" a simplified version of "let's say"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-choice

section 1.1 of the book "Introduction to Probability, 2nd Edition" says

> If S is a set and x is an element of S, we write x ∈ S.
>
> If S contains a finite number of elements, **say** X1, X2, ...

similar usage of “say” shows up everywhere.

Is "say" a simplified version of "let's say" here?

Comment: Say is used here to mean  *for example*. *Let's say* also works.

Answer (score 1):

In this case **SAY** indicates that the following text is **information given** to you to allow you to solve your mathematical problem.

**say** verb (**GIVE INFORMATION**) to provide information or instructions in writing: [Link C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/say)